# setState unexpected token using e.target.name

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

My onChange handler got unexpcted token, I would like to use e.target.name which I expect is keyword, what's wrong?

```
onChange = e => {
    this.setState({
        e.target.name: e.target.value //error here
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <section>
        <input type="text" name="keyword" value={this.state.keyword} onChange={() => this.onChange} />
</section>
)
}
```

Comment: Basically a duplicate of [Using a variable for a key in a JavaScript object literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274242/using-a-variable-for-a-key-in-a-javascript-object-literal).

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use computed property names, here's the syntax:

```
onChange = e => {
    this.setState({
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <section>
        <input type="text" name="keyword" value={this.state.keyword} onChange={this.onChange} />
</section>
)
}
```

Also you don't need to pass your `onChange` function inside an anonymous function. Simply reference it by passing it to the `onChange` prop.

Comment: Not only is it not necessary, it's wrong. They don't call the method.